# cucumber scala cannot construct scala option

Tags: scala, cucumber

I have this data in my feature in cucumber :

```
| deal | mir | stp1 | stp2 | date       | mnt |
| 1255 | 120  | 1   | 1    | 2018-01-01 | 120 |
```

that I read in that case class

```
case class test1 (deal : String, mir: String, stp1:String, stp2: String, date: Sttring, mnt:Option[String])
```

in my step definition I read it like that :

```
Given("""^I have this data$""") {dt: DataTable =>
    val dt_lists  = dt.asList(classOf[test1 ])
}
```

Problem : when I put "mnt" which is Option[String] in my data like that :

```
| deal | mir | stp1 | stp2 | date       | mnt |
| 1255 | 120  | 1   | 1    | 2018-01-01 | 120 |
```

I have an error :  cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot construct scala.Option : scala.Option : Cannot construct scala.Option

when I retrieve "mnt" from the data:

```
| deal | mir | stp1 | stp2 | date       | 
| 1255 | 120  | 1   | 1    | 2018-01-01 |
```

in that case the program works.

any help is welcome thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised why you want to convert `dataTable` to `case class`. If you are intended to use each field you can do something like this 
`

```
 Then("""^tGiven("""^I have this data$""") { (fieldNames: DataTable) =>
        fieldNames.asList(classOf[String]).asScala.foreach { fieldName =>
          // you will have all the field names here like deal,mir ,stp1 ,stp2,date,mnt 
        }
      }
```